# How to call a remote kie server

Tags: timeout, drools-kie-server

I implemented a kie-server on Wilfly and deployed a decision service.
Calling it on the same machine with Insomnia works fine, Just using http://localhost:8080.

Trying to make the same call from another machine using xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080 just runs into a timeout.

What am I doing wrong?
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved using portlistener.exe
Still wonder why the port is not opened by the server. Kie server claims it is.
Now I have another issue. See next question.